# MVC post method with multiple body parameters, why am I getting a 404?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC controller method defined like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EndBatchForConditions(string a, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

called with jquery like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        a: $form.find('#aCtl').val(),
        b: $form.find('#bCtl').val()
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ...
    },
    error: showError
});
```

This works on my local, and has been working on our test and production machines for about 6 months.

We are moving this from its own website to an application under another website, and have made the move on the test servers.  This method is giving me a 404, and everything else works fine.  Another method gets called the same way on the same controller with similar parameters, and it works fine.  I used Fiddler to verify the urls and requests for both methods are correct, and are exactly the same.

I know we are not allowed multiple POST body parameters using [FromBody] attributes.  Is this an incorrect way to make this call?  If not, how can I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Is your `url` that your passing in relative?

Comment: what is the value of "url" for the url property on the ajax call?

Comment: Can you confirm that #bCtl is found and has a value? If b is null then the signature of EndBatchForConditions does not match (int b is not nullable), resulting in a 404. Does it work when you change 'int b' to 'int? b'

Answer (score 0):

This was not a routing issue.  The method threw an exception, and global.asax.cs was redirecting to a missing error page, throwing a 404.